# Placing labels inside specified polygons/shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible to place labels inside specified polygons in QGIS?

Case: I have a material which consist of water areas and various small islands. They are separated shapefiles. I would like to label the islands so that the label is placed **always** on the water area (-shapefile) next to the island. The islands are not equal in shape and size so the normal x and y based placement method is out of the question.

Comment: Make centroid layer and then move labels where you want.

Comment: use the EasyLabel plugin to move the labels as required?

Answer (score 6):

I think one way is to use geometry functions on data defined placement.

Placement -> Data defined -> Coordinate x -> edit -> x_max( $geometry )
and same Coordinate y -> edit -> y(centroid($geometry)) OR maybe better: y_max( $geometry )

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, with following *Placement* parameters:

- Placement: *Using perimeter*
- Allowed positions: *Below line* & *Line orientation dependent position*
- Distance: 5.0 mm (for bigger text size)

[image]